# Detect which child is clicked on click of the parent

Tags: android

I have a layout which contains lots of images. What I have to do is when an image is clicked, I have to show its details. But I don't want to have onClickListeners for all the images. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to have different handlers for all the images. Instead use one handler for all the images. This would make your code cleaner, manageable and solve your problem too.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    //...

    OnClickListener mHandler = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.img1:
                    //..
                    break;

                case R.id.img2:
                    //....
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.img1);
    ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.img2);
    //...

    btn1.SetOnClickListener(mHandler);
    btn2.SetOnClickListener(mHandler);
    //...
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer.. Is the OnClickHandler class you mentioned in your code is your own class because I can't find it. If so, which class is it inheriting?

Comment: It is in View.OnClickListener. And also It is an interface. If you want you can implement the interface in your class and then call `btn.SetOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. I misspelled it as ``OnClickHandler`. It is ofcourse `OnClickListener`. I didn't notice it till now.

Comment: Thanks for correcting that.. Now the problem is that I have to setOnclicklistener to all the 20 odd images which I will have in my layout. Isn't there a way by which I can setonclicklistener only on the parent layout and then onclick of that I could check if a child at specific index is clicked or not.. Tell if you have any other idea regarding that.. What  I actually want is something like the google images do when you select an image, but rather than enlarging it I have to show some details.

Comment: Im guessing you are using something like a GridLayout then? or even a ListView? You can set onClickListeners and the view's would handle figuring out positions of index for you. This will be a better option if you are generating your images programatically. In case you just have 20 images in a linearlayout or something, setting an onclicklistener on the linear layout will work i *think*. You will get passed the event, But you will still have to do a getId() check to figure out which was clicked.

Comment: Thanks.. I think its probably better to use gridview then.. Now since I have to show detail for each image I will have to add a layout or something after each row.. So I will have to use separate gridviews with layouts in between where I can add content if the image is clicked.. Is there a way so that I can add a layout dynamically between those gridviews based on which image is clicked and add content to it.. If you have any other suggestions to achieve something like this, it will be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure. Really depends on the effect you want to achieve. You could try with Dialog Boxes or having a hidden linear layout with details next to each image in the grid view. and just making it visible onclick. But I'm not sure. I suggest you try something and if you face problems ask a new question about it. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

One `Listener` to rule them all.

1. Implement `onClick()` on an object, register it as listener
2. In `onClick()`, examine the `View` object passed as parameter to determine which of the images was clicked. You can do anything from `getId()` to casting it to `(ImageView)` and getting the actual image out.
3. Once you know which image was clicked, do what you will with it.

Comment: Implement onClick() on an object, register it as listener - do you mean implement OnClickListener interface and override the onClick() method?

Comment: Indeed. Then call `setOnClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to implement custom behavior for an `ImageView` (or whatever), and then have multiple instances of that type of view, you should subclass the `ImageView` and put your listener in there.  Then you've got an encapsulated `View` that implements the custom behavior you want, and if you decide later that you want more or less or them, or to put them in another place, it's easy to move the `View` and its behavior without ripping apart your `Activity`.